# swapAndLiquify - don’t swap & liquify if sender is uniswap pair - WHY?

Tags: swap

Contract states: swapAndLiquify - don't swap & liquify if sender is uniswap pair. Why is that so?

I just want to understand it better.

Comment: any conclusion on this?